# Do different variable types use different amounts of space in HTTP bodies?

Tags: http, network-programming

For example, if you were to add a String object to an HTTP body containing "123", would it use the same amount of bandwidth as an int with the numeric value of 123? Would they both be encoded into the same thing and transferred as text or is there some optimisation based on the type being encoded?